# Eclipse hangs when editing javascript

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I added Angular-eclipse plugin in my eclipse. now when i am trying to edit any of my javascript file my eclipse hangs.
for example whenever i put "." and wait for js suggestion my eclipse hangs with not responding. 
could any one assist on this.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue but how to fix is up to debate.  See https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/issues/109

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803945/eclipse-stuck-on-building-workspace-after-installing-angular-js

Answer (score 1):

I once had an issue in Eclipse, but with another JS framework which is Sencha EXTJS. Some people say Eclipse does not get along very well with JS, at that point when I was learning JS, I'd have liked to use IntelliJ but, you know, we want to save our bucks for the future :). In addition, I remember I installed the Sencha EXTJS plugin but same issue, my Eclipse hanged and I had to try to make my changes in a notepad, neh, just kidding, but yes, I faced a similar problem like you.

By that time I used to edit my JS using SublimeText, VIM or Aptana (you could also try them).

But, since you seem to like Eclipse (as much as I can, I love that IDE)... you can make something similar to what I did some time ago, follow the steps of the following guide:

http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/2013/04/24/configuring-eclipse-with-apache-tomcat-and-ext-js

Does not matter what your server is (neither your framework), I think this configuration steps can be the "basics" for what you need.

Hope it could help you or at least give you some clue on how to have the environment in which you can feel comfortable to make some code :).

Regards and happy coding :)

Comment: ..The link you pasted has been broken.Please copy paste the steps here directly so that this issue wont come up again.

Comment: http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/index.php/configuring-eclipse-with-apache-tomcat-and-ext-js/   is the link that Marcelo pasted in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

In your eclipse,

1) Go to Help

2) Click Eclipse marketplace

3) search - optimizer

install "optimizer for eclipse" 
[image]